# Is there a way to parse a filename for metadata using a workflow?

Tags: workflow

I would like to get metadata out of the filename using a workflow. Example - "PDF_DATE_USER.pdf"

Sharepoint columns:
Filetype: PDF
Date: DATE
User: USER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to this link:

http://www.aiim.org/community/blogs/expert/Theree28099s-Metadata-in-those-File-Names

My Example:

[image]